# How do I redirect back to protected page after user logs in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, backend

I am using express. I have a page `myprofile` which is only accessible when user is logged in. The problem is I cant redirect back to `myprofile` automatically when user gets logged in. I am using social media OAuth login / passport strategies.

After click on profile button, this happens :

`home --->isAuthenticated() ---> /login ---> /`

After click on profile button, I want :

`home --->isAuthenticated() ---> /login ---> /myprofile`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer. I didnt hope that it will so easy to tackle this problem.

Some changes that I did :

```
function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        // variable holding previous path 
        req.session.returnPath = req.path;
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}

.
.
.

  app.get('/auth/<provider>/callback',
    passport.authenticate(<provider>, {
        failureRedirect : '/login'
    }), 
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || "/");
        delete req.session.returnTo;
    });
```